# Excel order of formulas calculation wasting resources?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Excel calculates the parentheses from inside out right? If my formula starts with a simple =IF and has lots and lots of functions inside the false route, even if that logical test is true, Excel will still calculate everything inside the false route?

For example:
In cell B1: =IF(A1=0;0;IF(... PROCX ... PROCV ... whatever ...))
Even if A1 is actually 0, Excel will still run all those PROCs and whatever else BEFORE evaluating A1?

Comment: No. If A1 evaluates to 0, then the value 0 in your case, is immediately returned. The false path won't be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see exactly how a formula evaluates, use `evaluate formula`.

[image]